# Struct size error in CodeBlock

Tags: c, struct, size

I've defined the following struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int num_albaran;
    char cod_vendedor[5];
    char cod_cliente[5];
    char cod_articulo[5];
    int unidades_vendidas;
    char fecha_venta[5];
    float desc_aplicado;
    float total_venta;
} plantilla_venta;

typedef struct {
    long int num_registros;
    char blancos[36]; // tengo que meterle esa cantidad porque la estructura de ventas me da 40 a saber por que....
} plantilla_primer_registro;
```

When I use the `sizeof` function:

```
printf("%d - %d", sizeof(plantilla_venta), sizeof(plantilla_primer_registro));
```

I am getting the follow sizes:

```
40 - 40
```

This is incorrect, meaning I'm having trouble when I read or write data to my files. How do I correct this?

Comment: What is the size you expect? And why is it important?

Comment: @iharob When you are editing, please correct everything. Not just one line in a question like this.

Answer (score 0):

Its true as this struct should be 40 bytes.
Because :

`you have 2 integers = 2 * 2 bytes = 4 bytes. In some systems int is 2 bytes`

`4 char array of size 5 = 4 * 5 bytes = 20 bytes. An ascii char is 1 byte ( Unicode chars take 2 bytes )`

`2 float numbers = 2 * 8 bytes = 16 bytes.`

And if you sum them `8+20+16 bytes` they result in `40 bytes`, So what is the problem ?

Comment: Umm.. '8+20+16 bytes they result in 40 bytes'

Comment: Oh sorry , but as he says seems strange.

Comment: Maybe integer in his system is 2 bytes

Comment: ...or maybe the [5] arrays are being padded to force 16-bit alignment and the floats are 4 byte singles.

Comment: The two structures should be the same size. The first 36 and second 36 to 40 show wrong because they are 36. In codeblock the int var size are 4 bytes, float 4 bytes, char 1 bytes.... If I set char[10] i will have 10 bytes.... What happen? :S